# Realtek audio manager not opening no matter what I do

Tags: windows-10, realtek-hd-audio

A couple of days ago, I installed Realtek drivers to fix an issue with my sound. Ssince then I've noticed that my microphone has been really quiet, but there's no Realtek audio manager where I can find it. There is an EXE for it, however opening said executable doesn't work either. I've heard this is an issue often on Windows 10, however none of the fixes I've tried work. I've attempted restarting my PC, reinstalling it multiple times, I would've tried rolling back but that's not an option because of the reinstalls, etc. I'm on the latest Windows 10 version 1903 with the Realtek drivers version 6.3.9600.2240 (the latest it seems).

Comment: Please edit your question to include which version of Windows 10 you have installed and the Realtek driver version you have installed.

Comment: edited for needed info

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Outdated driver. It seems that, for whatever reason, the Realtek website hasn't been updated in years. [I found a GitHub repository with the most recent versions.](https://github.com/alanfox2000/realtek-hda-release/releases)

Answer (score 0):

If you open the device manager and select the audio controller in the list, go to its properties, instead of rolling back, go to Update Driver and select "Browse my computer for driver software" then you should be presented with a list of previous drivers you used. Select the first one which is the one that worked. You can do this for both Realtek and the default controller but you might want to uninstall everything, restart and then follow the steps above although it should work without uninstalling it.

Not sure about all of the rules on this site but I could fix it for you remotely in 5 mins as I'm sure many other Super Users here could if that was a choice.